# Gitlab-workhorse stopped working: “open config.toml: no such file or directory”

Tags: gitlab

We have a gitlab server that has been running for a long time without issues.

Today suddenly `gitlab-workhorse` (8.20.0) stopped working (all other services are fine):

```
gitlab-ctl tail gitlab-workhorse

....
{"build_time":"20200131.231313","level":"info","msg":"Starting","time":"2022-04-21T15:19:38+01:00","version":"v8.20.0"}
{"configFile":"config.toml","error":"open config.toml: no such file or directory","level":"fatal","msg":"Can not load config file","time":"2022-04-21T15:19:38+01:00"}
I can’t find any information on why this would happen, and it seems config.toml isn’t even part of the configuration of gitlab-workhorse.
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I am also facing same issue, My gitlab is on gcp.

Comment: Site was working out great from last 2-3 years. problem started today (around 7-8 hour back)

Additional Observations:

Full path of the missing file is "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/config.toml"

and content is :
# cat  /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/config.toml
[redis]
URL = "unix:/var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket"
Password = ""

if I run 
" ***sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure ***"

file gets created and site works for 3-5 minutes, after that file is missing again.

Comment: also i can see "usr/bin/httpd" running in ps, which is not suppose to be running.

Comment: Same situation as ours. Problem started suddenly after years of running the server without problems. We fixed our server with `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-workhorse-stopped-working-open-config-toml-no-such-file-or-directory/68589/5?u=eloy.villasclaras

Answer (score 0):

ref: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/11/04/action-needed-in-response-to-cve2021-22205/

steps followed:

1. kill and stop non git related process, and delete those exes from sudo user.

   ps -aef | grep git   # from output of this command find which are not by gitlabs

   ls -l /proc/< pid >/exe

   kill

   rm <path got from ls -l command>
2. Apply below patch, as explained in gitlab blog link above.

   cd ~

   curl -JLO https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/build/CNG/-/raw/master/gitlab-ruby/patches/allow-only-tiff-jpeg-exif-strip.patch

   cd /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/exiftool-perl

   patch -p2 < ~/allow-only-tiff-jpeg-exif-strip.patch
3. this is temp patch, need to upgrade gitlab version as next step